# Adding http:// in internal links

Tags: seo, search-engine-indexing

I was wondering if adding `http://` into my links was a bad thing for SEO optimization.

I know that is unnecessary but I have several links that are displayed in multiple subdomains.

I try to explain it better:

- The main site is in `http://www.example.com` and in every page there are some links to other pages
- I have, for example, `http://search.example.com` and `http://account.example.com` that has the same header with links that point to `http://www.example.com`

So, my question is, if the spyder goes to `http://www.example.com` and finds several links that point to `http://www.example.com/page1` instead of `/page1`, ecc. would this hurt indexing?